# Error with webpack image loader

Tags: css, angular, webpack, jhipster

My webpack configuration is -

```
{
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
loaders: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=content/[hash].[ext]']
},
```

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-
loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/color.png' in 
'D:\Work\Personal\Projects\CashbackCalculator\src\main\webapp\content\scss'
@ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-
loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss 6:284192-
284221
@ ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss
@ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
@ dll vendor
```

Comment: There could be some problem in setting the path in your config file. Care to show your config file?

Answer (score 3):

If you have `images`folder containing all the images, then you can try to load images as per code shown below :

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
use: [
         { loader: "url-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]" },
         { loader: "image-webpack-loader" }
     ]
```

It works for me!